# How many numbers in the matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

We consider a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a_{i,j}\end{bmatrix}$ with $r$ rows and $c$ columns. We fill this matrix only with zeros and ones.

How many ones (maximally!) we can write into the matrix $r\times c$ to not have any rectangle with ones at its vertices? Formally:
$$
\forall_{i_1,i_2\in\{1,\ldots,r\}} \ \forall_{j_1,j_2\in\{1,\ldots,c\}} \ \ \big( (i_1\neq i_2 \wedge j_1\neq j_2) \Rightarrow 0\in\{a_{i_1,j_1},a_{i_1,j_2}, a_{i_2,j_1}, a_{i_2,j_2}\} \big).
$$

For example, for $3\times 3$ matrix we can fill it with 6 ones:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
But when we use 7 ones, then there always is a rectangle with ones at its vertices. For example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf 1 & \mathbf 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
\mathbf 1 & \mathbf 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
But what is the maximal number of ones for matrix $r\times c$?

Comment: A simple (and not entirely straightforward) argument gives 2(r+c) as a weak upper bound. I suspect the answer is closer to 2max(r,c).  (Actually, a tweak gives the latter, which may still be weak.) Gerhard "And What Have You Tried" Paseman, 2019.08.09.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you just want to maximise the number of ones so that there is no 
$$\left[\matrix{1&1\\1&1}\right]$$
as a not-necessarily-contiguous $2\times 2$ submatrix.

Equivalently, how many edges can a bipartite graph with sides of size $r$ and $s$ have without having any 4-cycles?

This is the first non-trivial case of the [Zarankiewicz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem).

The square case is [A001197(n)-1](http://oeis.org/A001197).

There is a table of values and bounds in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5475). I have more exact values near the diagonal.

Comment: In particular, see OEIS sequences [A191873](https://oeis.org/A191873) and [A001197](https://oeis.org/A001197).

Comment: Also [A072567](https://oeis.org/A072567).

Answer (score 0):

For an $n \times n$ matrix, you can get $3 (n-1)$ ones by putting them in all entries except $(1,1)$ of the first row, first column and main diagonal.  That's optimal at least for $n \le 5$.

But for $6 \times 6$ the optimal solution has $16$ ones, e.g.

$$  \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 0&1&1&1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0
&1&1\\ 1&1&0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&1&0&1&0
\\ 1&0&0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&0&1&1&0
\end {array} \right] 
$$

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: It is a partial answer.  The complete answer is not known.